# "This watch dials in or into your location"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can "dial in" replace "dial into" in the following sentence? And do they both mean "to achieve a particular setting or configuration using a dial or similar instrument"?Thank you!

"[This watch dials into your location, and provides yardages to the front, back, and middle of the green to help you take your game to the next level](https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/garmin-approach-s10-golf-watch-with-preloaded-courses-granite/13013246)".

Comment: The sentence is nonsense advertising gibberish. What they are **trying** to say, is that the watch* obtains* your location (presumably using GPS as that is what Garmin are famous for), and then uses a list of known golf courses to give you information. You should completely ignore it for any assistance with good (or even comprehensible) English.

Comment: dial into means: The watch sends a signal about your location to the software; the software reads the yardages on the green where you are. And yes, it is GPS unless the golf course has towers to receive these signals at every green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what "dial into your location" means because it doesn't seem to make sense in this context. (PRL75 offerred a meaning in a comment above.)

The preposition "into" implies some kind of motion or direction. For example, in the days of "dial-up" Internet, a modem could "dial into" a remote server. If a server were at one's location, then a watch could "dial into" it.

Unlike "into", "in" does not have to be a preposition. I can "dial in my coordinates" or "dial my coordinates in". (In this case, "dial in" could be considered a phrasal verb or "in" could be considered as a separate adverb.) This would mean either that I entered my coordinates into the watch by means of a dial or that I sent my coordinates to a remote location.

Comment: location of the golfer on the golf course.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your detailed explanations 

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions literally mean achieve or narrow in towards a particular setting or configuration that tunes the attached device to a particular signal, usually a radio signal.

They are also both used figuratively to mean "locate".

They have slightly different mental concepts, but this product slogan is so vaguely worded that either one fits.

Comment: I *think* the "etymology" of ***to dial in*** derives from old-style telephone dials used to enter the desired number to connect to ***by phone line***. So it's not quite the same thing as the ***tuning*** dial on an old-style ***radio***. (Nor is it about ["Turn on, **tune in**, drop out"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_on,_tune_in,_drop_out) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers My feeling about both in this context has to do with tuning frequencies, though it's true that "dial in" also has the telephone meaning.